# Chrome embedding SVG results in infinite requests

Tags: google-chrome, svg, cross-domain, embed-tag

I'm migrating from self serving SVGs in my app to storing them out on Azure as a blob. Doing the following when the URL is being served by the app works fine:

```
<embed src="@Model.SensitivityUrl" type="image/svg+xml" class="svgcontainer" />
```

However, doing the same thing when the URL points at the azure blob makes the initial request fine:
[image]
Then Chrome starts making request after request for the same URL, all served by the cache, continuing until I either leave the page, or in this case, since I wanted to keep the logs, delete the element from the page:
[image]

Some further experimentation shows that this isn't an Azure issue, as embedding a SVG from wikimedia results in the same behavior:

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg" class="svgcontainer" />
```

And this seems to be Chrome specific, the exact same page, with the same embed pointing at wikimedia works fine.

So, in short, has anyone else run into issues using `<embed>` to put an SVG into a page in Chrome, when the SVG is hosted on another domain?